# Debugging on iOS 4.0.1 Device crashing

Tags: iphone, crash, debugging

Trying to fix a bug on iOS 4 but when I debug it crashes with these errors:
SDK is installed in seperate directory as I need to deug 3.1.3 as well

Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1

Device is running 4.0.1

Any ideas? Cheers

---

```
[Session started at 2010-07-27 14:26:45 +0100.]
Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1470) (Thu May 27 05:54:06 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.1/Symbols/usr" /System "/Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1
    Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.1/Symbols/System" /private/var/mobile/Applications/50A5673A-2D68-4EA2-B033-2CA40C8DFC79 /Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/029.LondonBusMaps/021.Bus.v2a.RedesignWithRoutes_iOs4Recompile/Bus/build/Debug-iphoneos /var/mobile/Applications/50A5673A-2D68-4EA2-B033-2CA40C8DFC79 /Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/029.LondonBusMaps/021.Bus.v2a.RedesignWithRoutes_iOs4Recompile/Bus/build/Debug-iphoneos  /Developer "/Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1
    Loading program into debugger…
    Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
    Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
    Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.1/Symbols/Developer"
    Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
    Undefined command: "Developer".  Try "help".
    Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Resources/Xcode SSHPassKey
    tty /dev/ttys001
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "dyld" (prefix __dyld_) (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libxml2.2.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "Foundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "CFNetwork" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreLocation" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "MapKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "MessageUI" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices" (file not found).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "MobileCoreServices" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "QuartzCore" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "SystemConfiguration" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libsqlite3.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libz.1.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libgcc_s.1.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "libobjc.A.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
    warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
    Program loaded.
    target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-407-23
    Switching to remote-macosx protocol
    mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
    mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
    mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
    (gdb) run
    Running…
    [Switching to thread 11523]
    [Switching to thread 11523]
    gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
    0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0013117d internal_vproblem + 316
    1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x001313c1 internal_verror + 43
    2   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x001313f6 align_down + 0
    3   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x001825b1 macosx_solib_add + 959
    4   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00196394 remote_macosx_complete_create_or_attach + 225
    5   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00196a0c remote_macosx_create_inferior + 1083
    6   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0006f9ad run_command_1 + 660
    7   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0012f132 execute_command + 713
    8   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001bf67 mi_execute_async_cli_command + 226
    9   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001b584 captured_mi_execute_command + 371
    10  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008546f catch_exception + 65
    11  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000188e2 mi_execute_command + 163
    12  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00018a87 mi_execute_command_wrapper + 50
    13  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008ae51 handle_file_event + 349
    14  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008a818 process_event + 131
    /SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1470/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-dyld.c:1547: internal-error: unrecognized shared library breakpoint
    A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
    further debugging may prove unreliable.

    The Debugger has exited with status 1.The Debugger has exited with status 1.
```

---

Someone asked had I created symlinks
A few months ago when 3.0.1 came out I had problems getting it to work with XCode and found this help:

Topic : iPhone OS 3.0.1 does not work with xCode

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2103502&tstart=0

So I ran this and it seemed to work.

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

The symbolic link no longer works so just wondering should I delete it.

---

Some notes on my installation layout
I have these installation directories:

```
Developer:                3.1.3 - works - app in AppStore
Developer3_2_Final:
Developer_4_0_Final_Xcode3_2_3:
Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1:    This is the version that crashes
```

---

The only symbolic link I created was under /Developer
yet crash caused when I use Xcode in /Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1

My app was built in 3.1.3 using /Developer so am loath to remove it.

---

not a unix guru though am willing to dive in so any pointers gratefully received.

The  /Developer_Xcode3_2_3_iOS_SDK_4_0_1 was installed yesterday and I ran the 3.1.3 against it and then debugger when running on device crashed.

So I have done nothing with any of these SDKs except create that symlink months ago and install SDKs above 3.1.3 in seperate directories till I was sure I could build against them.

---

Comment: Please block out your code, this question is *very* hard to read.

Also, I think iOS 4.1 is still under NDA.

Comment: LAST PART CUT OFF
/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1470/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-dyld.c:1547: internal-error: unrecognized shared library breakpoint
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.

The Debugger has exited with status 1.The Debugger has exited with status 1.

Comment: console output put in block as req.

Comment: You'll need to provide us with a lot more than just the one line of relevant console output.  What does the stack trace look like?  What does the code look like around the line where the crash occurs?

Comment: I updated the debugger output with the full stacktrace (theyd got cut off because debugger put in funny characters which I only noticed when I pasted it into Xcode editor) and added some more info/clues.
any help gratefully received.

Comment: Afraid I took a sledgehammer to it and completely deleted /Developer and installed the latest into it 4.0.1
Seems to be debugging on the device fine now.
Though if anyone has any ideas then do add as other might not be so fortunate